# Not able to run javascript for webview in android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview, android-webview

I have `html` string which i am loading into `webview`. Remember html is not a file, its just a string.
For example if we take my html string is,

```
String html = "<html>
   <head>
   <title>business card template-2</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

  </head>
 <body>
    <div id="name_text"><font face="verdana" color="#525405">Name</font></div>
   <div id="mobile"><font face="verdana" color="#525405">Mobile</font></div>
 </body>
</html>"
```

This html string i am loading into webView.

I am using script file to replace Name under font tag dynamically, that is , In the above html string in the place Name i wanted to replace with Actual Name and even in place of Mobile with actual number.

So i have attached the script to the above html string and that should do all that replacing work.

For example my script which i concatenated to html string is,

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var name_text='Rupesh';" var tel_no='XXX-XXX-XX'; </script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='file:///android_asset/js_files/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='file:///android_asset/js_files/template.js'></script>
```

That template.js and jquery.js files i have kept under `assets->js_files` folder so tried to access by giving path `file:///android_asset/js_files/template.js`

Inside template.js i am doing that replacement.

This works fine when i do it in pc browser by giving path to those two .js files. But in android mobile i am not able to load it. Is there any alternative to do this replacement.

Programmatically i am loading the concatenated string into `webview`
That is,

```
String html_script = html+script;
webViewCard.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webViewCard.loadData(html_script,"text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Can somebody help me with this.

**UPDATE:**

I have found solution for this but i am not extremely happy with this because of some restrictions.Here is the solution below,

I added following line of code

```
WebSettings settings = webViewCard.getSettings();
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
 }
```

But problem is i have to restrict my app only for 4.2 and above users.
Is there anything i can do.

Comment: do you have webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); in your code?

Comment: Yes you can see it above there. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

**1.If your phone/emulator runs on Gingerbread**

I faced a similar problem myself. I was using 2.3 Gingerbread(API 10) emulator to test my app. I found out more about it on [android forum](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987).

**2.If your phone/emulator runs on 4.2 Jellybeans**

From the From the Android 4.2 documentation:

> Caution: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you must
>   add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you want
>   available your web page code (the method must also be public). If you
>   do not provide the annotation, then the method will not accessible by
>   your web page when running on Android 4.2 or higher.

Comment: Where should i add the annotation??

Comment: Go through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript)

Comment: In my case i am not calling any method from script. I am just loading another javascript file (template.js) inside script tag. So how do i add interface.

Comment: No. It is just showing the html but script is not executing i think. If script runs then all placeholders should be replaced with values.

Comment: webViewCard.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html_script, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

Comment: Replace loadData with above line and try